# Can one thread access a synchronized non-static method and another thread access a synchronized static method at the same time?

Tags: java

I got this asked in an interview a few days ago. Can one thread access a synchronized non-static method and another thread access a synchronized static method at the same time? The methods belong to the same class. I know the answer is yes but I want to know how it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: What is the synchronization object? Same for both methods?

Answer (score 6):

The synchronization object for a non-static method is the object itself (`this`).

The synchronization object for a static method is the `.class` instance.

Both are different. Hence you can.

Answer (score 1):

Because syncrhonization is not enforced on the same two objects:

- first `synchronized` lock (for **non-static method**) is acquired over the **object instance**,
- second `synchronized` lock (for **static method**) is acquired over the **class instance**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a synchronized non-static method on a class, the lock object will be `YourClass.this`. If you have a static synchronized method on the same class, the lock object will be the `YourClass.class`. These are two different locks that does not mutually exclude each other. So that is the reason why the two threads can access the two methods in the same time.

Comment: `Class` makes me thing `java.lang.Class` (for obvious reasons), and in that case it is the same lock. :)

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to consider, is what object are those methods being synchronized on? For a non-static (just a regular, object method) it will be synchronized on the actual instance of the class (this - the object you create using 'new'). For a static method, you are synchronizing it on the class itself (there is no instance object).

These are two different objects, so the synchronization will not stop the methods running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

ObPedantry: Not if `this` is `java.lang.Class.class` (and the lock hasn't been released by calling a `java.lang.Object.wait`).